# Can I slide out pieces of laminate and replace?

Tags: laminate

The short edge of 10 planks is open from the family room to the kitchen.  No kitchen floor yet.  I want to change the curve to straight so that the kitchen tiles will have a straight edge. We Were not going to do tile when the laminate was laid. Can I pull out the 10 planks & push in 10 that are longer & then cut the edges straight across the opening instead of curved?  I cannot go to the long edge & remove planks until I get to the  ones I want changed.

Comment: A photo might be helpful, remember we can't see what you're taking about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. But remember that there's a tremendous amount of friction between adjacent pieces, and getting ones that have longer edges in contact out is going to need a lot of elbow grease.

I had to do this when laying laminate. Had about a dozen pieces that stopped short of the front door (we originally planned vinyl there and changed our minds), so had to remove these  shorter pieces and lay laminate across the entire area.

It helps to cut out a notch in the piece you're removing, then slot the smaller edge of your pull bar in, and use your hammer to remove the laminate. It's a long and noisy process, but can be easily done.

Comment: It's worth stating that this depends on it being a floating floor, where the planks are neither glued down to the subfloor nor glued to each other.